# Angular routing working on dev mode but not when starting as spring boot app

Tags: angular, spring-boot, routes, hash-location-strategy

I'm new to angular, using angular 10.

In "app-routing.module.ts", i can see below config to enable "#" in url

```
imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }) ]
```

**Problem:**
If i'm running application through vs code on dev server(4200 port) then it redirect url "http://localhost:8081/auth" to "http://localhost:8081/#/auth" and page is loading successfully.

but if i'm running application through intellij(port 8080) as a springboot application then it redirect to "http://localhost:8081/auth" with 404

can anyone please help how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You don't run it as a spring boot application. Spring boot starts a tomcat server that hosts your frontend.

Normally you have packed your compiled angular application in resources directory of spring boot project. Those get served as static files from tomcat when it runs.

Check that the actual static files that exist in resources folder are the right ones (correctly compiled files from your latest angular version)

Normally the built angular application is stored inside `/src/main/resources/static`

Intelij however will load the whole application from `target/....` So check if there your static angular files exist.